# How to read a POST response and look for specifics

Tags: php

I am coding a script to read the response given from a payment gateway after a transaction is done.
http://docs.merchee.com/api/push-notifications/index.html

The example data I am getting is

```
$received_values = "
    status_code PAID
    subtotal 10
    success_redirect http://site.com/thanks
    tax_total 0
    total_price 10
    transaction_amount 10
    transaction_date 07/24/2012
    transaction_nmb 101888
    transaction_time 12:43:52
    zip 12345 
";
```

I am specifically looking for the lines `transaction_nmb` and `status_code`.

I'm thinking I do something like so:

```
$received_values = (array) stripslashes_deep( $_POST );
```

But am stuck on how I should go about confirming it.. `in_array`?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you specifically looking to see if those lines exist, or looking to see what values those lines have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks like $received_values is a newline separated string, maybe you could use this regex (untested) to get the values?

```
preg_match_all('/status_code\s(\w+).+transaction_nmb\s(\d+)/',$received_values, $matches);
// PAID should be in $matches[1]
// 101888 should be in $matches[2]
```

Comment: Hi Tim, $received_values is turned into an array from what I have. However I haven't been able to double check what it is actually looking like from a var_dump due to the nature of the script. But it would be the same as turning any $_POST into an array...

Comment: Do you want to confirm the value exists? Or that the key exists? If it's an array, you should just be able to do something like $val = $received_values['status_code'];

Comment: Thanks for that I will look into it. I want to confirm the key exists.

Comment: Yes, if $received_values is in fact an array with the obvious key value structure, you can do if (array_key_exists('status_code', $received_values)) {}

Comment: I'll try   if (isset($received_values['status_code']) && $received_values['status_code'] == 'PAID'){
  return true;
  }

Answer (score 0):

Explode by newline (explode is not the most efficient but will help.

```
$array = explode('\n', $received_values);
```

This will give you this each line an a array.

```
$array[0] //status_code PAID
```

Then you can just look for the answer by splitting it again or using one of php parsing functions.